# Which tool to use to export SQL schema from ODBC database?

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I have a database in a format which can be accessed via ODBC. I'm looking for a command-line tool to generate SQL file with DROP/CREATE statements from it, preferably with all the information including table/field comments and table relations. (Possibly for a tool to parse the file and import the schema too, but I guess this would be relatively easier to find). Need this to automate workflow, to be able to design the database visually but store it in SVN in code form.

Which tool should I use?

If this helps, the database in question is MS Access, but I guess there's a higher chance of finding a generic ODBC tool...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I wrote the tool to export access schema/parse SQL files myself, it's available here:

https://bitbucket.org/himselfv/jet-tool

Feel free to use if anyone needs it.

Comment: Does this extract the data/records as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding this because I wanted to search an ODBC schema, and came across this post.  This tool lets you dump a csv format of the schema itself:

http://sagedataobjects.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/exploring-sage-data-schema.html

And then you can grep away..

Answer (score 1):

[This script](http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/db/mysql/Downloads/Contrib/Old-Versions/exportsql.txt) may work for you with some modifications. Access (the application) is required though.